# Selection Sort Problems

Tags: python, function, sorting, selection, built-in

I'm attempting to create a simple selection sort program in python without using any built in functions. My problem right now is my code is only sorting the first digit of the list. What's wrong?

Here's my sort

```
  def selectionsort(list1):
    for x in range(len(list1)):
      tiniest = minimum(list1)
      swap(tiniest,x,list1)
  return(list1)
```

Here's the minimum and swap functions I'm using

```
    def swap(index1,index2,list1):
       TheList = list1 
       temp = TheList[index1]
       TheList[index1] = TheList[index2]
       TheList[index2] = temp
       return(TheList)
    def minimum(list1):
       small = list1[0] 
       for i in list1:
          if i < small:
          small = i
       return small
```

An example of output
List = [3,2,1,0]

Output = [0,2,1,3]

Comment: What do you mean by it's only sorting the first digit?  Can you give example input, expected and actual output?

Comment: This does not look like *selection sort*, afaik, this is *bubble sort*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some simplification will make it more readable/comprehensible:

```
def swap(lst, i1, i2):
  lst[i1], lst[i2] = lst[i2], lst[i1]  # easy-swapping by multi assignment 

def minimum(lst, s):  # s: start index
  min_val, min_index = lst[s], s
  for i in range(s+1, len(lst)):
    if lst[i] < min_val:
      min_val, min_index = lst[i], i
  return min_index  # return index of minimum, not minimum itself

def selection_sort(lst):
  for i in range(len(lst)): 
    swap(lst, i, minimum(lst, i))  
    # find min index starting from current and swap with current
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems `minimum` returns the value of the smallest element in `list1`, but your `swap` expects an index instead. Try making `minimum` return the index instead of the value of the smallest element.